# How to use CSS Ribbon Generator code for specific featured images

Tags: css, ribbon

I want to use this code from CSS Ribbon Generator but only need it for certain featured images - not all.

I have CSS and HTML. It's not clear as to what file I would include the HTML in my child theme to get the CSS to work.

I only want the ribbon for certain featured images. All the plugins I've seen are outdated.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px; top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; right: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="ribbon"><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
```

How can add this code for use with specific featured images and which file would I place the HTML code in for the CSS to work?

Comment: How are you differentiating between featured and non-featured images?

Comment: I setup two podcast channels. This way I can change the code to just to point to that one channel I want the riboon on - maybe. That's about the only way I can think of to differentiate the two.

Comment: you can add a class to the images that you want ribbon on and using js you can apply ribbon to only specific items, i can help you with this approach, if you would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ribbon on only specific images by separating them from other images, and then using JS to add ribbon to only images that fulfill certain criteria.

Here I am using `featured` class to separate images from other images, and then using javascript to add `ribbon` class to those images.

```js
let feat = document.querySelectorAll('.featured')
feat.forEach((img)=>{
 img.classList.add('ribbon')
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px; top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; right: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
<div class="box">
   <div class="featured"><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="featured"><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class=""><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="featured"><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class=""><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="featured"><span>PREMIUM</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work but all the images are "featured" images in Wordpress. I figured by adding the premium and free content into two distinct podcast channels - I'll have a different class to point to so that not all featured images are marked premium. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I'm not proficient in javascript. In what file in my child theme would I place the javascript and should I ignore the HTML that was generated by the CSS Ribbon Generator?

Comment: @PartyFavorz i don't have much experience with wordpress, but you need to place this javascript just above the closing body tag `</body>`, make sure to place the script in `<script></script>` tags. Also regarding HTML, if it is what you want then go with it, all you need is a custom class for premium images.

Comment: That's in the header. I'll try it out shortly. Thanks so much!